# Is there an offline transaction checker for Monero in Python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for the same behavior as this site https://xmr.llcoins.net/checktx.html but in Python. The only method I have at the moment is to use a Monero CLI but this is not really efficient. If such a program does not yet exist, where can I find documentation on this subject to try it on my own?
Thank you